# How to do curl in Php to trigger and send a file to jenkins job (which accepts file as parameter)

Tags: php, curl, jenkins

I have to trigger a job on `jenkins` and upload the file at same time (`Jenkins` has file parameter set) from PhP page.

I know we can easily do this with curl unix command specified in `jenkins` Remote Access API. but I want to use php curl to trigger the job at same time upload the file.

I have written following code but it doesn't work .

```
<?php 
   $baseUrl="197.10.2.1:8080";
   $jobName="exampledatacopy";
   $json='{"parameter": [{"name":" /var/lib/jenkins/file/workspace/1.txt", "file":"@/home/kark/Desktop/1.txt"}]}'; 
   sprintf('%s/job/%s/buildWithParameters', $baseUrl, $jobName);
   $curl = curl_init($baseUrl);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
   curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
   $response=curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
?>
```

above code successfully triggers the job on Jenkins. Output of the job is as follows.

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/file/workspace
Finished: SUCCESS
```

but file is not uploaded. $response prints a response showing status of all jobs

Comment: Please specify how it doesn't work besides the immediate that it doesn't appear on Jenkins. Does it get executed totally, or is there an error coming out of it? If no errors, what is the $response code gotten? These are all relevant for your question and answering without these is really hard.